# I need a Javascript literal syntax converter/deobfuscation tools

Tags: javascript, arrays, syntax, literals, deobfuscation

I have searched Google for a converter but I did not find anything. Is there any tools available or I must make one to decode my obfuscated JavaScript code ?

I presume there is such a tool but I'm not searching Google with the right keywords.
The code is 3 pages long, this is why I need a tools.

Here is an exemple of the code :

```
<script>([][(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]][([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]]()[(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(+(+[])+[][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[+!+[]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]])(([]+[])[([][(![]+[])[+[]]+([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]]+(![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+[]]+(!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+[])[+!+[]]]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]+(!![]+
```

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you evaluate it?

Comment: A part of the code redirect users to Youtube.

Comment: Whoops, I think you're in trouble if that was your workable copy.

Comment: Fascinating stuff; could you possibly post a link to the entire code listing?

Comment: That code is designed explicitly as a joke; nobody writes actual JavaScript like that.

Comment: @Pointy or someone really wanted to hide their source and be a major pain in the back for any end users

Comment: maerics : It will not redirect everyone. My teacher said the script must meet a certain requirement.           Here is the code :) http://pastebin.com/1SA89SWD

Comment: With Firefox Linux version 3.5.16 the script redirects the user to Youtube.

Comment: I get "cannot convert undefined to object"

Comment: Raynos : I tested it with FireFox 3,5,16 Linux and it redirected me to Youtube.

Comment: @Raynos maybe but odds are it's somebody submitting something to wtfjs or something.

Comment: Raynos : When I copied the script it was copied with carriage return. Here is the link to the orignal code :) https://cours.etsmtl.ca/log619/documents/travaux/lab1/LOG619-Lab1-Boni.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already an accepted answer, but I will still post to clear some things up.

When this idea come up, some guy made a [generator](http://discogscounter.getfreehosting.co.uk/js-noalnum_com.php) to encode JavaScript in this way. It is based on doing `[]["sort"]["call"]()["eval"](/* big blob of code here */)`. Therefore, you can decode the results of this encoder easily by removing the sort-call-eval part (i.e. the first 1628 bytes). In this case it produces:

```
if (document.cookie=="6ffe613e2919f074e477a0a80f95d6a1"){ alert("bravo"); }
else{ document.location="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oHg5SJYRHA0"; }
```

(Funny enough the creator of this code was not even able to compress it properly and save a kilobyte)

There is also an explanation of why this code doesn't work in newer browser anymore: They changed `Array.prototype.sort` so it does not return a reference to `window`. As far as I remember, this was the only way to get a reference to `window`, so this code is kind of broken now.

Answer (score 4):

This code is fascinating because it seems to use only nine characters ("`[]()!+,;`" and empty space `U+0020`) yet has some sophisticated functionality.  It appears to use JavaScript's implicit type conversion to coerce arrays into various primitive types and their string representations and then use the characters from those strings to compose other strings which type out the names of functions which are then called.

Consider the following snippet which evaluates to the [array filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```javascript
([][
   (![]+[])[+[]]               // => "f"
 + ([![]]+[][[]])[+!+[]+[+[]]] // => "i"
 + (![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]]         // => "l"
 + (!![]+[])[+[]]              // => "t"
 + (!![]+[])[!+[]+!+[]+!+[]]   // => "e"
 + (!![]+[])[+!+[]]            // => "r"
]) // => function filter() { /* native code */ }
```

Reconstructing the code as such is time consuming and error prone, so an automated solution is obviously desirable.  However, the behavior of this code is so tightly bound to the JavaScript runtime that de-obsfucating it seems to require a JS interpreter to evaluate the code.

I haven't been able to find any tools that will work generally with this sort of encoding.  It seems as though you'll have to study the code further and determine any patterns of usage (e.g. reliance on array methods) and figure out how to capture their usage (e.g. by wrapping high-level functions [such as Function.prototype.call]) to trace the code execution for you.